# Record to a MemoryStream using NAudio

Tags: c#, stream, record, memorystream, naudio

I'm trying to use `NAudio` to record from the micrphone and save tthat data to a MemoryStream. There doesn't seem to be an obvious way and everytime I try to read from my `BufferedWaveProvider`, the recording no longer plays when using `WaveOut.Play`. It recording plays fine if I remove my read attempt. Is there a way to record to a MemoryStream?

This is how I've tried to convert it to a MemoryStream:

```
Byte[] stream = new byte[bwp.BufferedBytes]; 
bwp.Read(stream, 0, bwp.BufferedBytes);
wo.Play(); //plays fine only if I comment out the Read line above
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(stream);
```

Comment: please show how bwp is being used or defined where do you create this..?

Comment: what version of NAudio are you using..? here is a link you can look at as well.. http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/04/naudio-tutorial-5-recording-audio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a link out on code project along with the source code that you can download to help you to do what you are trying.

There is an example project on codeproject doing this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx
I don't know how low the latency is.

As a codec I'd recommend Speex(at least for speech). It's free, open source and offers low latency and low bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

A WaveProvider can only have one consumer of its Read method. I suggest that at the point you add bytes to your BufferedWaveProvider you also add them to your memory stream. The alternative is to inherit from IWaveProvider, and in the Read method, read from the BufferedWaveProvider and write what you read to the MemoryStream before returning. Then use that WaveProvider to give to WaveOut.